# How can i manipulate the ATN-Constant generated by ANTLR V4 for Java?

Tags: antlr4

I'm very new at ANTLR and use V4 to generate a lexer to integrate with netbeans.

The generated java-file gives me an error: "constant too long" at the serialized ATN. 
How can i configure ANTLR to generate an compliant String (ore more of them)?

kind regards 
Jan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a limitation of the first release of ANTLR 4 that has since been fixed. Here is the issue report:

[Serialized ATN strings should be split when longer than 2^16 bytes (class file limitation)](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/76)

Until ANTLR 4.1 is released sometime this Summer, you have two options:

1. Build a current version of ANTLR from source code, and use that.
2. Modify your lexer/parser to be simpler, thus requiring fewer states.

Comment: Thank you. I will give the actual Version a chance. Btw. You build a very good tool .